# MySQL Deleting duplications

Tags: mysql

I want to sort my database duplicates out via 'Telephone' I can only seem to delete them all instead of keeping one of the numbers

My code currently:

```
delete from costar  where (SELECT pnum FROM costar group by pnum having count(*) >= 2)
```

any help will be much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your WHERE clause will always be true even if you group by id and pnum which is the correct way to visualize duplicates. Try this instead:

```
DELETE FROM costar WHERE id IN
(
SELECT c2.id 
FROM costar_tmp c1, costar_tmp c2
WHERE c1.id <> c2.id
AND c1.pnum = c2.pnum
)
```

EDIT:

Updating solutions with the use of a temporary table that can be created with:

```
CREATE TABLE costar_tmp AS SELECT id, pnum FROM costar;
```

Comment: Hi mate, the select works perfect but i'm getting this error,                          #1093 - Table 'costar' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Create a 2nd temporary table 
    
    **CREATE TABLE costar_tmp AS SELECT id, pnum FROM costar;**

Then replace the costar in the subquery with costar_tmp and try again.

Comment: I have ran it and its deleted about 750 lines but when i run 'SELECT pnum FROM costar group by pnum having count(*) >= 2' to check how many are left im still getting 1500 , i had 1800 before.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Id, you could do something like the following.

```
  delete costar
  where  Id not in (
    select min(Id)
    from   costar
    group  by pnum
  )
```